# Converting IntVar() value to Int

Tags: python-3.x

Iam trying to convert `Intvar()` value to `Int` by

```
self.var1 = IntVar()
self.scale = ttk.LabeledScale(self.frame1, from_ = 3, to = 7, variable = self.var1).grid(row = 2, sticky = 'w')
value = int(self.var1)
```

but got an error saying

**TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'IntVar'**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Kapocsi I would like to convert the value i got from Intvar() to Integer
and Iam unable to do it due to above TypeError

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to invoke the .get method of IntVar which returns the object's value as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

See inline comment for info.

```
self.var1 = IntVar()
self.scale = ttk.LabeledScale(self.frame1, from_ = 3, to = 7, variable = 
self.var1).grid(row = 2, sticky = 'w')
value = self.var1.get() #the get() method of the IntVar object will return an int value
```

Hope this will help you!